# How to check code inside math library function sqrt() using Dev C++?

Tags: c++, c

I want to check code inside **math library function**  `sqrt()` how is it possible?
 I am using DEV C++ .

Comment: Please don't use Dev C++. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info

Comment: **Dev-C++ is not a compiler.**

Comment: @FredLarson You do realize that DevC++ has had a [recent update](http://orwellengine.blogspot.com/)?

Comment: @Mysticial: Interesting news! However, it's still hardly a recommended player in the IDE field. Perhaps after a few more updates it'll catch up.

Comment: @Mysticial: Well, I'll be! I thought it was abandonware. Maybe somebody should update the tag info.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Updated. Someone will have to approve and/or improve my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This stuff gets compiled into the toolchain runtime, but since GCC and its Windows port MinGW (which is what your Dev-C++ IDE invokes) are open-source, you can just take a look at the source.

Here it is for latest MinGW GCC; both versions appear to defer basically all of the work to the processor (which is not a great surprise, seeing as x86 — by way of the x87 part of the instruction set — [supports square root calculations natively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87)).

### [`long double` values](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/winsup/mingw/mingwex/math/sqrtl.c?rev=1.1.2.1&content-type=text/plain&cvsroot=src)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern long double  __QNANL;

long double
sqrtl (long double x)
{
  if (x < 0.0L )
    {
      errno = EDOM;
      return __QNANL;
    }
  else
    {
      long double res;
      asm ("fsqrt" : "=t" (res) : "0" (x));
      return res;
    }
}
```

### [`float` values](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/winsup/mingw/mingwex/math/sqrtf.c?rev=1.1.2.1&content-type=text/plain&cvsroot=src)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern float  __QNANF;

float
sqrtf (float x)
{
  if (x < 0.0F )
    {
      errno = EDOM;
      return __QNANF;
    }
  else
    {
      float res;
      asm ("fsqrt" : "=t" (res) : "0" (x));
      return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Square roots are calculated by the floating point unit of the processor so there is not much C++ to learn there...

EDIT:

x86 instructions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87

FSQRT - Square root

Even back in the day: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8087

Comment: Now that's shocking news to me... Any reference to back up your brave claim?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: Has that chip been used since the 80s? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87 is probably a better link.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit All right. I was just trying to prove that it is not news. ;-)

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu: I guess you're not paying attention :(]

Comment: Just read the full answer from @LightnessRacesinOrbit slowly and it should be clear. Also follow the links to the .c files in that answer.

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu: Why are you shouting at people? And not reading what they're telling you?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit now understood very well thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If there's no source code for your `sqrt()`, you can always disassemble it. Inspecting the code would be one type of checking.

You can also write a test for `sqrt()`. That would be the other type of checking.

Comment: What sort of "test" would that be?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There are many tests you can do: negative arguments, +/- 0, small positive arguments (normalized and denormalized), large positive arguments, exact squares, +/- infinity, NaNs, see that it's indeed calculating square roots (using predefined values or an alternative sqrt() function), see that it's accurate, see that it's monotonic, etc. You can throw in performance testing too. Is that good enough for a start?

Comment: I suppose, though it'd be a rather haphazard way of reverse-engineering the code behind your implementation's `sqrt`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't mean testing as a way of reverse-engineering, though it may reveal certain innards.

Comment: What _did_ you mean it as, then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: checking as in checking it works as expected.

Comment: It will. The OP would like to know how it is implemented by his toolchain. (I'm used to mentally translating "check" to "check out" when reading Asian English.)